# Default browser xml stylesheet when referenced xsl stylesheet is not found?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, browser

I would like the raw XML to be displayed when my stylesheet is not found by the browser, is it possible?

Below I have put the header of my XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./my_sheet.xsl" title="relativeRef" alternate="YES"?>
```

When the stylesheet is not found on my server I return a 404 error but this makes the XML parser of browser stop and displaying an error message. What should I do? Here is the JAVA code of the servlet which serves the stylesheet.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {      

    edamisUtils.log("Serving my_sheet.xsl");

    //If we could not load my_sheet we throw a 404 error.
    if(my_sheet== null){
        edamisUtils.debug(5, "Did not find the my_sheet.xsl, sending a 404 status response.");
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        return;
    }

    //Set the MIME type of the response to text/xsl
    resp.setContentType("text/xsl");
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    os.write(my_sheet.array());

}
```

Thanks all and have a nice day!

Comment: So nobody has an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know exactly if there is a fallback available since it depends on the implementation of each browser. You will have to include this processing instruction dynamically when you create your XML.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea when generating the XML which browser will read it. It would force me to modify the XML on the fly according to the browsers which request it...

Comment: Thats the problem of every web content :) But you asked for a fallback when the XSL is not available, not for a browser determination. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: You are right I want a fallback when XSL is not available.

Comment: Yes, and I said it's very doubtful whether this exists since the browser has to have this implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a 404, you could return a 200 and a "copy-all" XSL.

Something like

```
if(my_sheet == null){
   copy the copy_all XSL in the response output stream;
}
```

A copy-all XSL example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141216/xsl-copy-the-entire-xml-except-a-parent-node-but-keep-its-child-node)